# sql complex group query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with the following rows:

```
id. type  - link 

 1. image - http://1
 2. image - http://2
 3. text  - none
 4. video - http://..
 5. image - http://..
 6. text  - http://..
```

I want to group the type (image) by date, so they show as single row.  In this example, the first two images will merge together and output will be like following:

```
1. image - http://1, http://2  ** GROUPED BY DATE, if they are same type and not break type after it.
2. text  - none
3. video - http://..
4. image - http://..
5. text  - http://..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  grouper, type, GROUP_CONCAT(link)
FROM    (
        SELECT  @group := @group + (NOT (COALESCE(@type, type) = type)) AS grouper,
                @type := type,
                m.*
        FROM    (
                SELECT  @group := 0,
                        @type := NULL
                ) vars,
                mytable m
        ) q
GROUP BY
        grouper
```

Comment: great it works, but can you also please tell me, how can i just group images only and avoid text from grouping too?

Comment: SOLUTION:
SELECT  grouper, @type, type, GROUP_CONCAT(thumbnail), count(*), date_format(created_date,'%H %k %I %r %T %S %w')
FROM    (
        SELECT  @group := @group + (NOT (COALESCE(@type, type) = type) or type = 'feed')  AS grouper,
                @type := type,
                m.*
        FROM    (
                SELECT  @group := 0,
                        @type := NULL
                ) vars,
                feed m
order by created_date desc
        ) q
GROUP BY grouper

Comment: this query was working fine, but until i start showing other users media feed also, which means it also group there media as same user.. how can we seperate the groups for each different user seperately, even if the next row is same as previous row.

Comment: can you help on this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366597/how-to-make-slow-query-faster

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL you can do this :

```
SELECT id, type, group_concat(link) 
FROM table
GROUP BY id, type
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, type, group_concat(link) from table
```

Try that.

Comment: MaxiWheat: yeah oops. Rabid: the question IS tagged mysql

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete mind bending equivalent example for SQL Server 2005 and beyond:

```
create table #Temp
    (GroupField int, ValueType varchar(10), Value varchar(2048))

insert into #Temp (GroupField, ValueType, Value) VALUES (1, 'image', 'http://1')
insert into #Temp (GroupField, ValueType, Value) VALUES (1, 'image', 'http://2')
insert into #Temp (GroupField, ValueType, Value) VALUES (2, 'text', 'none')
insert into #Temp (GroupField, ValueType, Value) VALUES (2, 'video', '30mins')
insert into #Temp (GroupField, ValueType, Value) VALUES (2, 'image', 'http://5')
insert into #Temp (GroupField, ValueType, Value) VALUES (3, 'image', 'http://4')
insert into #Temp (GroupField, ValueType, Value) VALUES (3, 'text', 'hello')
insert into #Temp (GroupField, ValueType, Value) VALUES (3, 'image', 'http://7')
insert into #Temp (GroupField, ValueType, Value) VALUES (4, 'image', 'http://0')

    SELECT GroupField, ValueType,
           LEFT([Values],LEN([Values]) - 1)   AS [Values]
    FROM   (SELECT GroupField, ValueType,
                   (SELECT value + ', ' AS [text()]
                    FROM   #Temp AS internal
                    WHERE  internal.GroupField = GroupFields.GroupField and internal.ValueType = GroupFields.ValueType 
                    FOR xml PATH ('')
                   ) AS [Values]
            FROM   (SELECT  GroupField, ValueType
                    FROM     #Temp
                    GROUP BY GroupField, ValueType) AS GroupFields) AS pre_trimmed;
```

Produces the result:

```
GroupField   ValueType    Values
1            image        http://1, http://2
2            image        http://5
2            text         none
2            video        30mins
3            image        http://4, http://7
3            text         hello
4            image        http://0
```

It might need some `ORDER BY` clauses for your particular case ... adapted from [Rational Relational - Emulating MySQL’s GROUP_CONCAT() Function in SQL Server 2005](http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/11/emulating-mysqls-groupconcat-function.html)